# Customizing WPF DatePicker Mask

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I need to change the string format of the DatePickerTextBox in the WPF DatePicker to "dd/MM/YYYY" insted of "mm/dd/yyyy".
I want to allow users to add a date manually.
When i'm typing in TextBox in this format: "mm/dd/yyyy" the date in DatePicker Changing. But when i'm typing in this format: "dd/MM/yyy" i'm getting an error.
I tried: StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy' but it didn't help:

```
       <DatePicker x:Name="DateGviya" Text = "{Binding NameOfMyProperty, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, TargetNullValue=''}">
                <DatePicker.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy', RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DatePicker.Resources>
            </DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an exception on `ConvertBack` method:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '14/09/2016' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedDate; DataItem='DatePicker' (Name='DateGviya'); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='PART_TextBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Data.SystemConvertConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

So, providing a custom converter solves the problem:

```
public class MyCustomDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
            return ((DateTime)value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", culture);

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact((string)value, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", culture);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication293.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication293"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="350">

<Window.Resources>

    <local:MyCustomDateConverter x:Key="Converter1" />

</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <DatePicker x:Name="DateGviya" SelectedDate="{Binding CurrentDate}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <DatePicker.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt', RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, Converter={StaticResource Converter1}}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DatePicker.Resources>
    </DatePicker>
</Grid>
```

[image]