# WPF - DatePicker Masked input

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I'm developing an WPF application and I got two datepicks input where  use 
can select the date, But I am having some problem with these inputs cause the user can write whatever they want on it as in the image bellow

[image]

Is there some way to mask this inputs ? as dd/mm/yyy to only  allow users to  write dates and it automatically inserts the / slash ?

I tried follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752736/customizing-wpf-datepicker-mask) but didn't work  as it only formate the date after the user choose it from the calendar

I know that there are some "masked inputs" but they don't work with datepicker input

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT**

here is my  xaml code

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource InputBorder}" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DatePicker  x:Name="EDT_DATA_INICIAL"></DatePicker>
</Border>

<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10 0 10 0" Style="{StaticResource InputBorder}" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">
   <DatePicker  x:Name="EDT_DATA_FINAL"></DatePicker>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `PreviewTextInput` event in your DatePicker and handle the logic in there. The below example will restrict input to numbers and "/" only. You will have to figure out how to automatically input the "/" on your own if you wish to do that.

Maybe loop through each character of the string as it's built and determine if you need to add the "/" at a certain point. You can `e.Handled = true` to block the user input then set the `DatePicker.Text` as required. This should be enough to get you started.

```
private void DatePicker_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)sender;
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9/]"); //regex that matches allowed text
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);

    }
```

Regex reference is`System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Comment: I tried using this method with an regex but didn't work, I'm writing a code I'll post it here later

Comment: How was it behaving?

Comment: Finally I decide use your code, mine was getting a bit complex so I just format the date when  use digite only numbers in the DatePicker input I posted the complementation bellow

Answer (score 3):

Just complementing the @Tronald's answer I'am  using his event PreviewTextInput

and I complementend it using this code in a keyUp event

```
 private void SetDateFormat(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DatePicker dt = (DatePicker)sender;
        string justNumbers = new String(dt.Text.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
        if (justNumbers.Length == 8)
        {
            string newDate = justNumbers.Insert(2, "/").Insert(5, "/");
            try
            {
                dt.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(newDate);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                dt.text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

That format the date when  use only  digite numbers or 
ex : 18061993 > 18/06/1993 and when the date is incorrect it clears the input preventing errors

[image]